# C++ Tasks.json VS Code not taking arguments correctly

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code

Beginner here with build task configuration with C/C++ files. As I have to put the following command every time in the terminal; which is perfectly compiling my code.

`g++ Test.cpp -I/usr/include/opencv4 $(pkg-config --libs opencv4) -o Test`

But when I want to use `tasks.json` for directly running the code I've set up a configuration like this.

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "${file}",
                "-I/usr/include/opencv4 $(pkg-config --libs opencv4)",
                "-o",
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

But when running this task, it's giving error like in the screenshot provided.
[image: error screenshot]

What should I put in the args array to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

So, I got it working but setting each individual library as a separate string in the args array, which is required by the code. Now the args key should look like the following:

```
"args": [
                "-I/usr/include/opencv4",
                "-lopencv_imgcodecs",
                "-lopencv_highgui",
                "-lopencv_imgproc",
                "-lopencv_core",
                "${file}"
        ]
```

Also, now the build is running successfully.
[image: terminal on build]